# Using for each to iterate class properties

Tags: vb.net, class, for-loop, each

I have this class

```
Public Class TExperience
    Public ID As Integer
    Public CompanyName As String
    Public Country As String
    Public Years As Integer
    Public Months As Integer
    Public JobTitle As String
    Public Function Arr() As String()
        Return {"ID", "CompanyName", "Country", "Years", "Months", "JobTitle"}
    End Function
End Class
```

and this is how it work

```
Public Function Set()
    Dim D As New TExperience
    D.CompanyName = "Any Data"
    D.Country = "Any Data"
    D.ID = "Any Data"
    D.JobTitle = "Any Data"
    D.Months = "Any Data"
End Function
```

I need to exchange this by "For Each....." in class

```
        D.CompanyName = "Any Data"
        D.Country = "Any Data"
        D.ID = "Any Data"
        D.JobTitle = "Any Data"
        D.Months = "Any Data"
```

How to do this?

Comment: For Each is for iterating a collection - not needed here.

Comment: is there any way to do it here or any way else to do what i need ?

Comment: Its not at all clear to me what you are trying to do. To 'set' all those members thru one method, I would use the constuctor

Comment: i want to set data to all variable using for each

Comment: for each variable in d

Comment: Once again, For/Each is for iterating items in a collection. `TExperience` is not a collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, this is possible if... 
**Note:** you posted class with public fields, e.g. `Public CompanyName As String`. While it is usually good idea to use properties - `Public Property CompanyName As String`. The code below is for class properties but you can substitute `PropertyInfo` for `FieldInfo`. However, it is recommended to use properties to expose class values.
If you're looking for yes/no answer to question, *can setting properties via for-each happen?*, the answer is *yes*. But more questions about your question should arise. *When, why, what for...*, etc.

For example, we have a situation that specific types have common properties with other types, sometimes even deriving from those types and we need to convert them. One way was to use a "Decorator" pattern. But here is what we've done to hydrate properties  (disclaimer - code was converted from c# via converter and I added some tings like "as type", I am not sure it is 100% correct)

```
''' Everything "S" - source, "D" - destination. "T" - type
Public Shared Function Hydrate(Of TS, TD)(source As TS, destination As TD) As TD

    Dim sPI() As PropertyInfo = 
        source.[GetType]().GetProperties(BindingFlags.[Public] Or BindingFlags.Instance)
    Dim dPI() As PropertyInfo = 
        destination.[GetType]().GetProperties(BindingFlags.[Public] Or BindingFlags.Instance)

    For Each s As PropertyInfo In sPI
        Dim d As PropertyInfo = 
            dPI.FirstOrDefault(Function(pi) pi.Name = s.Name AndAlso pi.PropertyType = s.PropertyType)
        If d IsNot Nothing Then
            d.SetValue(destination, s.GetValue(source, Nothing), Nothing)
        End If
    Next
    Return destination
End Function
```

So, here we go. In this example properties iterated and when their names and data types match exactly, they are populated. But other than hydration of similar models, what is the use of it? I mean, this is what happens internally when JSON being deserialized, etc. But in everyday programming you don't do anything like this.

Comment: Be aware that this code would not work on the OP class as that class does not have any properties.  `GetProperties` would not return anything on the OP class.

Comment: ...also I *think* the OP was wanting to iterate the member names from that `Arr` function

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Hey, clearly... I am answering the question, regardless of OP code. The question was *"...iterate class properties"*

Comment: @Plutonix See above^^

Comment: Not to quibble - it is a useful enough answer - but *properties* was added to the question as a result of your edit; the OP never mentioned it.  I dont think the OP knows the difference between a Field and a stream

Comment: @Plutonix oops. I clarified the situation in the answer. Sorry. The original question was just like... what?

Answer (score -1):

What you're asking for is not possible.  As you have been told, `For Each` is for performing the same action for each item in an enumerable list.  The properties of an object are not an enumerable list, therefore `For Each` is not applicable in this case.  The way to set multiple property values is just as you are doing now.

That said, when setting multiple properties on a just-created object, you can use object initialiser syntax, e.g.

```
Dim D As New TExperience With
{
    .CompanyName = "Any Data",
    .Country = "Any Data",
    .ID = "Any Data",
    .JobTitle = "Any Data",
    .Months = "Any Data"
}
```

Obviously not what you were asking for but still an improvement on what you're doing now.  Alternatively, if the object requires all that data, it is preferable to declare a constructor with appropriate parameters, that way, the call MUST provide the data.  You've still got to set each property individually inside the constructor though.

Comment: I don't see how this pertains to anything specifically when there's no clear question involved. Why spend the time rephrasing the comments above when it doesn't bring any value to back your proposed solution as you clearly stated its not what he was asking for. IMO ask for clarification first... On another note, using with for instantiation is good, but again its case by case and we clearly don't know what that is.

Comment: @Zaggler, I think it's fairly obvious that the OP considered the multiple properties to be set to be a list and they wanted a way to enumerate that list. I think that providing information on how to set those property values better is worthwhile.